# Java Netbeans Restfull service gives me "infinite JSON"

Tags: java, json, jsp, rest, netbeans

I have just started using Restfull web services that Netbeans provide.

I have created two **Entities**. First is **Player** and second is **VehicleDetail**.  The both have ManyToMany relationships:

Player:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "players", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<VehicleDetail> vehicleDetails;
```

VehicleDetail

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Player> players;
```

I have created JSP pages where you can create new Players and VehicleDetails. I have added Restfull web services for my entities. They will provide me information about entities as JSONs.

When I add new Players and VehicleDetails through my JSP pages then I test Restfull service by GET HTTP method, it shows me right JSON.

Then I have added VehicleDetail to my Players list and Player to VehicleDetails list and updated both of them:

```
Player player = db.getPlayer(playerId);
VehicleDetail detail = db.getVehicleDetail(detailId);

player.getVehicleDetails().add(detail);
detail.getPlayers().add(player);

db.updateObject(player);
db.updateObject(detail);
```

Code for **db.updateObject(Object o)** is:

```
@Override
public void updateObject(Object o) {
    em.merge(o);
    em.flush();
}
```

Now, when I try to see my Player. I create HTTP GET method to see Player as JSON. It shows me "INFINITE" JSON. It shows me that it got VehicleDetail that got this Player that got this VehicleDetail that got this Player and so on. And it gives me exception;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException$Reference
```

Question: What I need to do? FETCHTYPE.LAZY does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [**@JsonIgnore**](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) annotation to one of many-to-many relationship sides.

```
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "players", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore
   private List<VehicleDetail> vehicleDetails;
```

or

```
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore
   private List<Player> players;
```

Comment: My Project does not have that kind of library. I have Glassfish 3.1.2.2. So I need to download this library??

Comment: @Mr.D If you have `maven` proj, then you should add it as dependency. Also you can try to add `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient` annotation istead

Comment: I have XmlTransient annotation, does not work. Also my project is not maven. Can I just add *.jar file?

Comment: @Mr.D Yes,you should add jackson library at compilation phase

Comment: I have added **jackson-annotations-2.4-** jar file to my project. Then added `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` to my VehicleDetail class. Does nothing, it throws exception and says there is infinite recursion and StackOverflowError.

Comment: @Mr.D You shoud add **@org.codehaus.jackson.annotate**.JsonIgnore` annotation

Comment: @Mr.D http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

Comment: There is no `JsonIgnore` annotation in library that you provided.

Comment: @Mr.D Sorry. jackson core you need http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

Comment: Теперь все работает просто отлично! Спасибо вам за помощь, и прошу прощения за нубские вопросы.